# Create function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using the function create in MongoDB, I try to create a project like:

```
req.body= {
    "_id":"58cc16d1e05208e123000004",
    "name":"Ivan",
    "surname":"Blabla",
    "position":"engineer",
    "__v":0
}

Project.create(name: "sample", users: req.body, function(err, project) {...
```

but it is not working, it seems that field names cannot be a string. Is it anyway to transform it directly or any function in mongoDB or mongoose?

Comment: it is working with something similar to
`req.body= {
    _id:58cc16d1e05208e123000004,
    name:'Ivan',
    surname:'Blabla',
    position:'engineer',
    __v:0
}`

Comment: JSON.parse() I think I found the solution